# how to align html dialog left or right with Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, dialog

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog
I am having a little fight with the the html dialog element in Firefox.
I would like align the dialog left / right and don't know how to do it properly.

By default it is centered
My workaround is to position the parent element

```html
<div style="position:fixed;right:0;width:10cm;">
  <dialog id="dlg" open>bla bla</dialog>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine. I thought it was not a [block element](https://www.w3resource.com/html/HTML-block-level-and-inline-elements.php) but I seem to be wrong since this displays the same in Chrome and FX

```css
dialog {width:10cm;}

#dlg1 {position:fixed;top:75px; right:0}
#dlg2 {position:fixed;top:143px; right:0}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed;right:0;width:100%">
  <dialog id="dlg" open>bla bla</dialog>
</div>

<dialog id="dlg1" open>bla bla</dialog>

<dialog id="dlg2" open>bla bla</dialog>
```